# How to Apply changes to resource.resx file during runtime(for changing language)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, localization, globalization

How to Apply changes to resource.resx file during runtime my code is below,
my problem is resource file is resorce.resx is changing but am getting it only after second reload

```
            string xmlPath = Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml");
            string resourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/LocalResource/Resource.sv-SE.resx");
            System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath);

            ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter(resourcePath);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "string")
                    writer.AddResource(reader.GetAttribute("name"), reader.ReadString());
            }

            writer.Generate();
            writer.Close();



   //here I set it to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");     
        CultureHelper.CurrentCulture = id;
        //
        // Cache the new current culture into the user HTTP session. 
        //
        Session["CurrentCulture"] = id;
        //
        // Redirect to the same page from where the request was made! 
        //

        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to change file.
You must create several resource files with various culture
for example Message.resx , Message.fa.resx , Message.fr.resx 
visual studio can detect current culture and load suitable file
for implement multi language feature you have two approach.
1- use base controller and inheritance

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private const string LanguageCookieName = "MyLanguageCookieName";
    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[LanguageCookieName];
        string lang;
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            lang = cookie.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            lang = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultCulture"] ?? "fa-IR";
            var httpCookie = new HttpCookie(LanguageCookieName, lang) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) };
            HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(httpCookie);
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
        base.ExecuteCore();
    }
}
```

2- use attribues

```
public class LocalizationActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string LanguageCookieName = "MyLanguageCookieName";
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[LanguageCookieName];
        string lang;
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            lang = cookie.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            lang = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultCulture"] ?? "fa-IR";
            var httpCookie = new HttpCookie(LanguageCookieName, lang) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SetCookie(httpCookie);
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

[culture code lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx)

Comment: hi,every thing is working fine for me detecting language ,converting language,but am try to fill resource.resx ie table from xml.That is show above.and binding from xml to resource table also working fine but problem is during runtime if i change xml , resources table is updating .but languge maped in the resource table is mapping only for the second time ie after reloading